# Java exceptions at different functions

Tags: java, exception

Hello there/ I am new to java and I am trying to make a program that parses through a txt file and scan its content line by line. Well,in the begging I designed the program without any object or classes apart the main and it worked fine. Then I wanted to design a new class with the content from the main function but it fails to compile and I get many exeption errors. Here is the code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;


public class Reader {


Reader(String file) throws Exception{
    Entry test= new Entry();

    File f= new File("C:/Users/Mario/Documents/Visual Studio 2013/Projects/Entry/Entry/a.txt");
    System.out.print(f.exists()); // true is printed on the screen when this was at main

    FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("C:/Users/Mario/Documents/Visual Studio 2013/Projects/Entry/Entry/a.txt");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));

    String strLine;
    String tag="";
    String date="";
    int id;
    String title="",description="",reference="";

    while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null){

        System.out.print(strLine+ "\n");
        if(strLine.length()>2 && strLine.substring(0,3).equals("I1:") ){

            System.out.print("id detected\n");
            id=-1;
            strLine = br.readLine();
            id=Integer.parseInt(strLine);
            //System.out.print("ID:"+id+"\n");
            test.set_id(id);
            continue;
        }

        if(strLine.length()>2 && strLine.substring(0,3).equals("T1:") ){
            System.out.print("title detected\n");
            title="";
            strLine = br.readLine();
            title=strLine;
            //System.out.print("Title:"+title+"\n");
            test.set_title(title);
            continue;
        }

        if(strLine.length()>2 && strLine.substring(0,3).equals("D1:") ){
            System.out.print("description detected\n");
            StringBuilder descrp=new StringBuilder();
            description="";
            while(true){                    
                strLine = br.readLine();
                if(strLine.equals("D2:")) break;
                else descrp.append(strLine);
                continue;
            }
            description=descrp.toString();
            //System.out.print(description);
            test.set_description(description);
        }

        if(strLine.length()>2 && strLine.substring(0,3).equals("D3:") ){
            System.out.print("DATE"+date);
            strLine = br.readLine();
            date=strLine;

            test.set_date(date);
        }

        if(strLine.length()>2 && strLine.substring(0,3).equals("R1:") ){

            strLine = br.readLine();
            reference=strLine;
            System.out.print("Reference"+reference);
            test.set_reference(reference);
        }
        br.close();
    }
}
}
```

and these are the errors I receive:

```
    true
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at java.io.BufferedReader.ensureOpen(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
    at Reader.<init>(Reader.java:28)
    at FileReader.main(FileReader.java:14)
```

What confuses me is the fact that I received these errors when I changed the file the code was. Before I got no errors at compilation and the program worked fine. The new file (Reader.java) is at the same directory like the file the main function is. I work at the Eclipse IDE. Thx in advnace

Edit: I added the throw exception at the function and thus changed the console output

Comment: So...why are you doing all of that in the constructor?  Also, the exception is pretty straightforward - since you're using a file there, you either wrap the usage of the file in a `try...catch` block, or add `throws IOException` to the signature of your method (which, in this case, would be your constructor).

Comment: I can't figure out why there were no exceptions before I move this piece of code in the other file. At main there was none of this problems.

Comment: I'm willing to bet a that `main` had either a `throws` or a `try...catch` block.  If it didn't, your main method wouldn't compile either.

Comment: I tried what you said and this is the output in the console:Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Stream closed
 at java.io.BufferedReader.ensureOpen(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
 at Reader.<init>(Reader.java:28)
 at FileReader.main(FileReader.java:14)

Comment: @Mario, close it AFTER the loop. Just take the close statement, one bracket down

Comment: @peeskillet wow you saved me! It would take me an eternity to find this. I feel like a retard :P Thx a lot man!

Comment: @Mario You should try to differentiate between runtime and compiletime

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `br.close()` statement is in the wrong place. It is being closed at the end of the loop, so when you get more at the beginning of the loop, the stream is closed. You just move the `br.close` outside of the loop.

Comment: Yes as @peeskillet told me at the comments. I know C/C++ decently and I thought that I would get an error like segmentation fault. Thx for the help!